# git client: how to use distinct local interface (or bind address) for http

Tags: git, curl

How do we tell the git client which local ip address it should use to connect a remote repository?

When using ssh, we can use the `BindAddress` option in the ssh client config. But when using http?

git appears to be dependent on curl, and in curl one would use the `--interface` option for interactive use. There is also a `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` variable, but that does not seem to work from the environment.

Comment: Indeed, this is generally a libcurl issue. Unfortunately Git itself never calls `curl_...` with `CURLOPT_INTERFACE` at all, so you might have to build a private version of Git. Before you go that far though, consider whether your OS has routing options so that you can get it to choose the right interface for the right target IP address: this would affect all requests, not just Git, if that's good or bad.